# How to make while read faster (how to use grep instead)

Tags: linux, sed, while-loop, grep, command

I have a file named "compare" and a file named "final_contigs_c10K.fa"
I want to eleminate lines AND THE NEXT LINE from "final_contigs_c10K.fa" containing specific strings in "compare".
compare looks like this :

```
k119_1
k119_3
...
```

and the number of lines of compare is 26364.
final_contigs_c10K.fa looks like :

```
>k119_1  
AAAACCCCC  
>k119_2  
CCCCC  
>k119_3  
AAAAAAAA  
...
```

I want to make make final_contigs_c10K.fa into a format :

```
>k119_1
AAAACCCCC
>k119_3
AAAAAAAA 
...
```

I tried this code, but this code takes too much time, though it seems to be working fine. I think it takes too much time because the number of lines in compare is 26364, which is too much compared to my other files that I had tested the code on.

```
while read line; do sed -i -e "/$line/ { N; d; }" final_contigs_c10K.fa; done < compare
```

Is there a way to make this command faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[">" $1];next}$1 in a{p=3} --p>0' compare final_contigs_c10K.fa
>k119_1  
AAAACCCCC  
>k119_3  
AAAAAAAA
```

This will produce the output to stdout ie. won't make any changes to original files.

Explained:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                        # process the first file
    a[">" $1]                    # hash to a, adding > while at it
    next                         # process the next record
}                                # process th second file after this point
$1 in a { p=3 }                  # if current record was in compare file set p
--p>0                            # print current file match and the next record
' compare final_contigs_c10K.fa  # mind the file order
```

Comment: Hi, @James, this gave me a file with >k119_2 ... instead, so I edited compare to list matching lines k119_2 ... and the code you gave me worked.

Comment: OK, good you got it fixed. The inputs must be exactly correct (including newlines `\r\n` vs. `\n` etc).

Comment: Ok, thank you. The answer Cyrus gave (deleted now) also worked with edited compare (k119_2 ...)  $ grep -w -A 1 -F -f coverage_contigs final_contigs_c10K.fa | grep -v -F -- '--'  > final_contigs_match.fa
Thank you for your help. @James Brown